# Hibernate Validator: Intercept Invalid Values

Tags: java, annotations, guice, hibernate-validator

I'd like to set up my beans to use both Hibernate Validator (for validation) and Google Guice (for DI and method interception).

Ideally, I'd like to have a setup where any method that "fails" validation will cause a method interceptor to be called:

```
public class Widget {
    @NotNull
    public Fizz getFizz() {
        return fizz;
    }
}

public class FailedWidgetInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        // This gets executed if Widget's getFizz() returns null...
    }
}
```

But it looks like Hibernate Validator only allows you to determine pass/fail status by explicitly passing an object `T` to a `ClassValidator<T>`'s `getInvalidValues()` method.

So I need a place to make such a call!  The **only** viable solution I can think of is to create my own annotation (which I've *never* done before!) which might look like this:

```
@NotNull
public @interface AutoValidatingNotNull {
    // ...??
}
```

And then in Guice `Module`:

```
public class WidgetModule implements Module {
    public void configure(Binder binder) {
        binder.bindInterceptor(
            any(),
            annotatedWith(AutoValidatingNotNull.class),
            new ValidatingWidgetInterceptor()
        );
    }
}

public class ValidatingWidgetInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        ClassValidator<Widget> widgetValidator = new ClassValidator<Widget>();

        InvalidValue[] badVals = widgetValidator.getInvalidValues(widget);

        if(badVals.length > 0)
            handleFailedValidationAndThrowRuntimeExceptionOrSomething();
    }
}
```

Finally, to change `getFizz()`:

```
@AutoValidatingNotNull
public Fizz getFizz() {
    return fizz;
}
```

For one, this only *almost* works: inside the interceptor's `invoke` method, **how do I get my hands on the `widget` instance (the one we wish to validate)?**. Is there a way to pass the `widget` instance via annotations?

**Edit:**
Doesn't look like I can pass `Object` into annotations (as parameters)...

Second, this is kind of nasty. Perhaps I'm overlooking something that Hibernate Validator offers that takes care of all this for me? Is there a better way to go? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're still using the Hibernate Validator 3.x API around `ClassValidator` et al.

I recommend to upgrade to 4.2 where an [API for method validation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customoptions-methodvalidation) was introduced which exactly does what you describe.

An example for the required glue code to integrate that API with Google Guice can be found in [this project](https://github.com/gunnarmorling/methodvalidation-integration/tree/master/methodvalidation-guice) which I created a while ago on GitHub.

Comment: Wow. Gunnar you are a great man in my book... thats weird I'm looking at your code now and realized I am sitting here trying to solve a problem that already has the exact solution I need. You even called your annotation `@AutoValidating`...deja vu! Thank you!

Comment: Hey, quick question: any chance your methodvalidation-guice project is in maven somewhere? I'm looking in the central repo and not finding it. It would be nice to declare this as a dependency to my project. Thanks again for all your help to all of my AOP/validation questions!

Comment: No, the project is not in Maven Central nor any other repo. I started the entire project more or less as playground for integrating the method validation feature until others stepped up. As of Spring 3.1 they have support for it out of the box and for CDI there is Seam Validation, so my project on GitHub is more or less obsolete, the Guice part being an exception. I recommend to just copy the required parts into your code base and adapt them as required.

Comment: Last question - in `ValidationInterceptor.java` you have a `ValidatorFactory` that is injected and used to procure a `MethodValidator`. Where can I find `ValidatorFactory`s that I can use for this injection?

Comment: `javax.validation.ValidatorFactory` is part of the Bean Validation API as defined by JSR 303 of which Hibernate Validator 4.x is the reference implementation. If you're using Maven, add `org.hibernate:hibernate-validator` as dependency to your pom.xml, this will transitively pull in `javax.validation:validation-api` which contains `ValidatorFactory`. There is also a [quickstart guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-gettingstarted) which shows how to set up a project using Hibernate Validator and Bean Validation.