# Is there a way to figure out the field on which a custom field constrained failed

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I am using Hibernate Validator to validate an entity. Is there a way to figure out which fields failed the validation before I throw the errors back to the UI(JSF)?

Comment: You should take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/8853795/3543153

Comment: @DamienBoue Thanks will do.

Comment: How are you using Hibernate Validator? Are you calling the Validator methods yourself or do you rely on some integration to do the validation? If you make the validation call yourself, then you should get a set of ConstraintViolations back which have a whole set of meta data you can query, eg the failing value and the path to  the failing property. If you rely on some integration code you need to check the documentation on how the constraint violations are made accessible.

Comment: No I do have the hold of the violations.